# Simple chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a simple chrome extension:
manifest.json

```
{

    "name": "Hello World",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
    },
    "description": "My First Chrome Extension",
    "browser_action": {

        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"

    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "<all_urls>"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*"],
            "js": ["js/script.js"]
        }
    ]

}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    });
});
```

scripts.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
        "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension");
        if (request.greeting == "hello") {
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
            document.write(request.greeting);
        }
    });
```

popup.html

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

The new button correctly appears in my chrome window, but when I click it an empty dialogue is created although I would it expect it to say "hello". Any advice?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want js/script.js to be a popup script *and* a content script.  Review the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Answer (score 0):

If you set `"default_popup": "popup.html"` in your manifest, chrome open a window to display your html page. So remove this line from the manifest (no need popup.html file) and in background.js do something like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the answer here; as I read the question carefully OP seems to want "hello" to appear in the popup.

Answer (score 0):

> an empty dialogue is created although I would it expect it to say "hello"

You are calling `document.write` from the content script, not the popup code - so it's writing to the actual active tab, not the popup.

To show something in the popup, you need to interact with its `document` from popup's code.